# Unable to associate MPNID to verify publisher

Tags: azure-active-directory

This is related to an active directory application that i am trying to associate with my publisher / MPN Id.
Been at it for over two weeks now.

So the situation is :
The app belongs to my sub-entity ( a separate MPNID from my global entity)
I created a new tenant to host my app and i created an app registration there.
The tenant has a verified domain which is different from my main company tenant domain.
When i try to associate the MPN id of my sub-entity, it errors out.

'The MPN ID you provided (....) does not exist, or you do not have access to it'

Any ideas?
The logged in user (in the new tenant) is provided with global admin priviledges in main partner portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [associate the new tenant in your Partner Center account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/multi-tenant-account). Keep in mind that the MPN (ID) account must be the Partner global account (PGA) for your org, not location.

Comment: partner center does allow multiple publisher accounts to be setup. My efforts were directed to keep offerings of my subsidiary companies in their own publisher + MPNID. but this seems like a limitation.